# Can I set custom location in CLLocationManager in iPhone

Tags: ios, swift, core-location, cllocationmanager

I am working on a compass app showing true heading (i.e directs towards true north) which uses location as described by apple documentation

> IMPORTANT
>   This property contains a valid value only if location updates are also enabled for the corresponding location manager object. Because the position of true north is different from the position of magnetic north on the Earth’s surface, Core Location needs the current location of the device to compute the value of this property.

what i want to do is that if the user's device is not connected to internet or the user denies permission to access its location then I take coordinates manually from user and give these coordinates to CoreLocation for a correct true heading. is this possible?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: I would also be comfortable with the obj-c code

Comment: I dont think what you are asking is possible, you'll have to make a second CLLocation or CLLocationCoordinate2D and use that if a real coordinate is not available.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you are asking for isn't possible using CoreLocation directly.  With LocationManager, if you want true north, you must call 'startUpdatingLocation` so that headings can be returned with true north values.  There isn't a method to set the location manually for LocationManager to use.

However you can calculate true north based on the magnetic value returned. You could have the user set their general location manually, as part of the setup, and store it for use when calculating true north. You could use a basic lookup table with locations and magnetic declination values. Kind of like a real map and compass would use. However, magnetic declination values change over time so you would need a way to update it.

If you are not familiar with magnetic declination, here is a [pretty good link from REI](http://www.rei.com/learn/expert-advice/compass-declination.html) That should give you the basic concept.

These links provide more details on how to calculate magnetic declination:

NOAA - http://www.ngdc.noaa.gov/geomag/WMM/

iOS - https://github.com/stephent/ObjectiveWMM

lookup Table - http://www.societyofrobots.com/robotforum/index.php?topic=11855.0

Comment: the link you provided proved your answer